# Terminology: If $A, B$ are subspaces of $V$ and $A \cap B = \{0\}$ then they are ......?

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology

If $A, B$ are subspaces of $V$ and $A \cap B = \{0\}$  then ...

1. If $V = A \oplus B$ they are *complementary*, otherwise
2. I think that Halmos describes them as *disjoint* but this seems at odds with the inference from set theory that then $A \cap B = \emptyset$
3. I would suggest *linearly independent*, as a generalization of two vectors being linearly independent.

Is there an accepted standard term for this ?

Comment: ... have trivial intersection

Comment: I would say, *disjointish*.

Comment: Seconding @HagenvonEitzen with "trivial intersection." The same term used for subgroups where the intersection consists of only the identity element..

Comment: I'd call them *direct summands*.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Thanks. So I would "adjectivise" this and say that $A, B$ are *trivially intersecting*.

Answer (score 2):

See  in a  vector spaces , every subspace has a  0 element . So the intersection contains atleast  0. I also read Halmos  for this and i use the term  disjoint  in order not to say the whole thing again and again.